# Outlook events not firing

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to send an email based on a calendar reminder going off.

I'm having trouble getting VBA macros to recognize that an Outlook event has occurred.

I put this code in a Class Module:

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 'also tried with double quotes around "Outlook.Application"
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox ("test")
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_NewMail()
    MsgBox ("test")
End Sub
```

When I get a new email or a reminder goes off, nothing happens.

I've tested with this macro in a normal module and it works:

```
Sub MsgBoxTest()
    MsgBox ("test")
End Sub
```

I have macro settings on "Enable all macros" in the Trust Center.

I've searched google, stackoverflow, a bunch of other websites, and read the documentation on Microsoft.com.

I'm on Outlook 2016 on a PC running Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this method, often used in documentation, run `Initialize_handler` manually or run it at startup in the special class module `ThisOutlookSession`.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

A class module is just a *blueprint* for an object. A class module doesn't exist all by itself, at runtime a class module is just a *type* that an object variable can be declared as.

Your code is fine (leaked public field aside).

You're just missing an *instance* of that class. Keep the class and make `ThisOutlookSession` create an instance of it:

```
'[ThisOutlookSession]
Option Explicit
Private AppEvents As AppEventsHandler

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set AppEvents = New AppEventsHandler
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set AppEvents = Nothing
End Sub
```

VBA classes fire an `Initialize` event on creation, and a `Terminate` event on destruction. Handle them to set your `Private WithEvents` field:

```
'[AppEventsHandler] (class module)
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Outlook.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set app = Outlook.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub app_NewMail()
    'TODO handle app event
End Sub

Private Sub app_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    'TODO handle app event
End Sub

'...more handlers...
```

That's it - now you're handling `Outlook.Application` events in a dedicated class, without polluting `ThisOutlookSession` with the nitty-gritty details of every event handler out there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle Reminder events, you need to enclose your code in a Sub named "Application_Reminder"

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox "Test"
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to indicate the code goes in ThisOutlookSession.