# Send email reminder when task occurs

Tags: vba, outlook

This code works with Outlook's Task system. I created a task that reoccurs every week on Wednesday. When the task occurs the code is suppose to send an email to "test@work.com" (not the real test email).

I have written the code in the Outlook VBA developer window.

Am I missing a step to get the code to run? The code logic is posted below.

```
Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objPeriodicalMail As MailItem
 
    If Item.Class = olTask Then
       If InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "Send PM Work Order Request Reminder Email") Then
          Set objPeriodicalMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
          
          
          With objPeriodicalMail
               .Subject = "REMINDER-Get Work Order Request Submitted"
               .To = "Test@work.com"
               .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Hello All Pm's, Please Submit your Work order request by 9:00A.M.</HTML></BODY>"
               .Attachments.Add
               .Importance = olImportanceHigh
               .ReadReceiptRequested = True
               .Send
          End With
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.reminder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002026/outlook-events-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

To control Outlook objects from outside Outlook, you must establish a reference to the Outlook object library from the project in which you are writing code. To do this, use the `References` dialog box in the Visual Basic Editor in the primary application. You can then write code that returns a reference to the Outlook `Application` object. Through this reference, your code has access to all the objects, properties, methods, and constants defined in the Outlook type library.

Read more about that in the [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) article.

To set up events you need to define the source object `withevents` or select in the drop-down list on VBA editor and select the required event. See [Using Outlook Visual Basic for Applications to Respond to Outlook Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-outlook-visual-basic-for-applications-to-respond-to-outlook-events).